# How to return only the first occurrence of something in an Array

Tags: java, loops

**Context:**

We have an array of bird's statuses.

```
bird {
 power:
 ...
 ...
 home:
 ...
 ...    
 status:
    [0] {age: 2, name: 'John'}
    [1] {age: 4, name: 'Gary'}
    [2] {age: 10, name: 'David'}
    [3] {age: 10, name: 'Jake'}
    [4] {age: 8, name: 'Steve'}
 phone:
 ...
 ...
}
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to get the name of the bird whose age is 10.

However there are several birds with the same age. I want the name of only the first occurrence.

**Required end result:**

The result I want it to return is 'David'.

**Current result:**

I am getting 'David' and 'Jake' being returned.

**What I have done:**

```
List<BirdStatus<?>> birdStatusesToTake = bird.getStatuses().subList(0, bird.getStatuses().size());    

    for(BirdStatus birdStatus : birdStatusesToTake){
      if (birdStatus.getAge() == 10) {  
        System.out.println(birdStatus.getName());  
      }
    }
```

**My question:**

How can I return the name of only the first bird whose age is 10?

Comment: I have tried things like indexOf() etc but still have not been able to get the desired result.

Comment: You have a `return` statement. So, it will not proceed once you find a match. So, you must be getting only `David`

Comment: Is this in a method?

Comment: yes it is within a method

Comment: @EagleOne from where do you call that method?

Comment: @user7 sorry my bad, result is being written to an excel file. I have wrongly replaced it by 'return'; I have modified the question and put system.out.println instead.

Comment: Why?  didn't the `return` work? and please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this if you are using java 8 or later:

```
bird.getStatuses().stream().filter(s -> s.getAge() == 10).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

In your code use `break` :

```
for(BirdStatus birdStatus : birdStatusesToTake){
  if (birdStatus.getAge() == 10) {  
    System.out.println(birdStatus.getName()); 
    break;  //here you can use return birdStatus.getName();
  }
}
```

Comment: `break` or just `return birdStatus.getName()`

Comment: well, its like he already had this (one edit ago), but changed it to printing, who knows why??

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger in fact i don't want to return it... i want to write it to an excel file directly here.

Comment: if you want to write it to an excel. then after write you can use break or return

Comment: @EagleOne **in fact** you asked (at least twice)  "How can I return..." its very hard to guess your thinking's over the internet

Comment: ok thanks, let me try all these and mark answer correct if all ok.. thx

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a counter starting at 0, put the if statement in a while loop which works only if the counter is 0, and then in  the if body add 1 to the counter:

```
int counter = 0;
while ( counter == 0){for(BirdStatus birdStatus : birdStatusesToTake){
      if (birdStatus.getAge() == 10) {  
        System.out.println(birdStatus.getName());
        counter ++;

      }

}
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over just `break`ing?

Comment: Why do you use an `int` for something that is essentially a `boolean` flag?